# How to handle Boolean value in Chai protractor promise

Tags: protractor, chai, chai-as-promised

I have tried to validate the Boolean value in chai promise as below,

```
 expect(2==2).to.eventually.equal(true);
```

But I got the below error:

```
 E/launcher - true is not a thenable.
```

Can anyone help me how to validate the Boolean value using chai promise.

Answer (score 0):

`eventually` means that you are resolving a promise.

2==2 is not a promise.

```
expect(2==2).to.equal(true);
```

Comment: Yep, but when I use .to.equal it working fine in true case, In false the whole feature file get stops. It not proceeding with next scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

This is close, try this

```
expect(2==2).to.be.true;
```